# Assigning customers to a territory, by grabbing all customers of a certain type, and a subset of another type

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to assign customers to a territory. I have six customer types, 0 to 5. All customers of types 2, 3, 4, and 5 get assigned to the territory they belong to automatically. While those of type 0 and 1 should be assigned based on the their score (because there is too many of this type). There is a limit of 15 customers to be chosen per territory.

The final output should have `territory` and an `id` of the chose customer. I struggle with how I could use something like a While loop to create the final list.

I tried to write some code, but I didn't go very far with my function.

The final output should be a data frame, with two columns, territory, and id for the top 15 customers selected in that territory.

The sample data:

```
{'id': {30: 31,
  71: 72,
  48: 49,
  3: 4,
  96: 97,
  27: 28,
  58: 59,
  47: 48,
  50: 51,
  81: 82,
  24: 25,
  57: 58,
  63: 64,
  12: 13,
  21: 22,
  29: 30,
  38: 39,
  53: 54,
  1: 2,
  97: 98,
  4: 5,
  75: 76,
  8: 9,
  43: 44,
  72: 73,
  41: 42,
  7: 8,
  0: 1,
  80: 81,
  64: 65,
  17: 18,
  67: 68,
  77: 78,
  13: 14,
  78: 79,
  95: 96,
  98: 99,
  18: 19,
  83: 84,
  39: 40,
  49: 50,
  62: 63,
  59: 60,
  19: 20,
  28: 29,
  32: 33,
  94: 95,
  76: 77,
  40: 41,
  25: 26},
 'customer_type': {30: 0,
  71: 0,
  48: 0,
  3: 0,
  96: 0,
  27: 0,
  58: 0,
  47: 0,
  50: 0,
  81: 0,
  24: 0,
  57: 0,
  63: 0,
  12: 0,
  21: 0,
  29: 0,
  38: 0,
  53: 0,
  1: 0,
  97: 0,
  4: 1,
  75: 0,
  8: 2,
  43: 5,
  72: 0,
  41: 0,
  7: 0,
  0: 0,
  80: 0,
  64: 0,
  17: 0,
  67: 0,
  77: 1,
  13: 0,
  78: 0,
  95: 0,
  98: 0,
  18: 0,
  83: 2,
  39: 0,
  49: 0,
  62: 0,
  59: 0,
  19: 1,
  28: 0,
  32: 0,
  94: 0,
  76: 0,
  40: 0,
  25: 0},
 'territory': {30: 'MP',
  71: 'MD',
  48: 'JW',
  3: 'KO',
  96: 'PC',
  27: 'MP',
  58: 'JW',
  47: 'KO',
  50: 'MD',
  81: 'JW',
  24: 'JW',
  57: 'JW',
  63: 'MP',
  12: 'MP',
  21: 'PC',
  29: 'PC',
  38: 'MD',
  53: 'PC',
  1: 'MD',
  97: 'MP',
  4: 'PC',
  75: 'MP',
  8: 'MD',
  43: 'JW',
  72: 'JW',
  41: 'MP',
  7: 'MP',
  0: 'MP',
  80: 'MP',
  64: 'MP',
  17: 'JW',
  67: 'PC',
  77: 'JW',
  13: 'KO',
  78: 'JW',
  95: 'MP',
  98: 'KO',
  18: 'PC',
  83: 'MP',
  39: 'JW',
  49: 'KO',
  62: 'JW',
  59: 'PC',
  19: 'MP',
  28: 'PC',
  32: 'MD',
  94: 'MD',
  76: 'KO',
  40: 'JW',
  25: 'KO'},
 'line_of_business': {30: 'MS',
  71: 'PL',
  48: 'PL',
  3: 'BK',
  96: 'BK',
  27: 'MS',
  58: 'MS',
  47: 'PL',
  50: 'PL',
  81: 'PL',
  24: 'MS',
  57: 'MS',
  63: 'MS',
  12: 'MS',
  21: 'MS',
  29: 'MS',
  38: 'PL',
  53: 'MS',
  1: 'PL',
  97: 'BK',
  4: 'BK',
  75: 'BK',
  8: 'PL',
  43: 'BK',
  72: 'WH',
  41: 'MS',
  7: 'BK',
  0: 'BK',
  80: 'MS',
  64: 'MS',
  17: 'WH',
  67: 'MS',
  77: 'PL',
  13: 'PL',
  78: 'MS',
  95: 'BK',
  98: 'PL',
  18: 'BK',
  83: 'BK',
  39: 'BK',
  49: 'BK',
  62: 'WH',
  59: 'BK',
  19: 'BK',
  28: 'MS',
  32: 'PL',
  94: 'PL',
  76: 'PL',
  40: 'BK',
  25: 'BK'},
 'score': {30: -0.11663294,
  71: -0.11386547,
  48: -0.12162866,
  3: -0.12182722,
  96: -0.11615907,
  27: -0.11718783,
  58: -0.114151105,
  47: 0.25628838,
  50: -0.12141464,
  81: -0.10258331,
  24: 0.38833429999999997,
  57: -0.11875506,
  63: -0.11688472,
  12: -0.12182722,
  21: -0.12166456,
  29: -0.12143712,
  38: -0.121612154,
  53: -0.1117985,
  1: 0.009443938,
  97: -0.08405101,
  4: -0.11209511,
  75: -0.11695675,
  8: -0.09269947,
  43: 16.203058,
  72: -0.12164523,
  41: -0.11750265,
  7: 0.23497310000000002,
  0: -0.12079343,
  80: -0.12140889,
  64: -0.09675851,
  17: -0.1216441,
  67: -0.11624039,
  77: -0.10221161,
  13: -0.120783366,
  78: -0.030865802999999997,
  95: -0.12078334,
  98: -0.12087545,
  18: -0.12182722,
  83: 2.497704,
  39: -0.09235809,
  49: -0.12162312,
  62: -0.120798856,
  59: -0.12138289,
  19: 0.45566094,
  28: -0.11319951,
  32: -0.028370887,
  94: -0.11610924,
  76: 0.006734696,
  40: -0.115899056,
  25: 0.208569},
 'rank': {30: 100362,
  71: 87381,
  48: 198190,
  3: 219184,
  96: 95523,
  27: 112584,
  58: 89707,
  47: 21080,
  50: 180328,
  81: 67077,
  24: 12142,
  57: 145717,
  63: 104471,
  12: 222278,
  21: 205690,
  29: 184550,
  38: 193153,
  53: 74821,
  1: 29773,
  97: 41429,
  4: 76400,
  75: 107456,
  8: 53003,
  43: 256,
  72: 202272,
  41: 117718,
  7: 23262,
  0: 164623,
  80: 177756,
  64: 60792,
  17: 202027,
  67: 96223,
  77: 66835,
  13: 162515,
  78: 35534,
  95: 162508,
  98: 168744,
  18: 217151,
  83: 3956,
  39: 52385,
  49: 196564,
  62: 164880,
  59: 172787,
  19: 9120,
  28: 83165,
  32: 34985,
  94: 95174,
  76: 30020,
  40: 92385,
  25: 26342}}
```

**EDIT INSERTED FROM COMMENTS

In response to a comment by run-out, which is appreciated by the way, so after all the customer types 2 to 5 have been picked, for each territory, then we pick those of type either 0 or 1 based on their score. Those with the highest score are picked first until we get to the 15th position, at which point the loop, if used, should exit, and iterate for another territory to fill another 15 positions. Customer types 2 to 5 get first priority, followed by types 0 and 1. Assume types 2 to 5 can be treated the same, while 0 and 1 are the same too.

```
# if implemented correctly the final output for territory JW should be:
df_result = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": {
            43: 44,
            24: 25,
            78: 79,
            39: 40,
            77: 78,
            81: 82,
            58: 59,
            40: 41,
            57: 58,
            62: 63,
            48: 49,
            17: 18,
            72: 73,
        },
        "score": {
            43: 16.203058,
            24: 0.38833429999999997,
            78: -0.030865802999999997,
            39: -0.09235809,
            77: -0.10221161,
            81: -0.10258331,
            58: -0.114151105,
            40: -0.115899056,
            57: -0.11875506,
            62: -0.120798856,
            48: -0.12162866,
            17: -0.1216441,
            72: -0.12164523,
        },
    }
)
```

And the out put is:

```
print(df_result)

    id      score
17  18  -0.121644
24  25   0.388334
39  40  -0.092358
40  41  -0.115899
43  44  16.203058
48  49  -0.121629
57  58  -0.118755
58  59  -0.114151
62  63  -0.120799
72  73  -0.121645
77  78  -0.102212
78  79  -0.030866
81  82  -0.102583
```

Comment: I've added a pandas tag, as i'm sure pandas will solve this easily. BUT, you need to be more clear on your output. I was hoping to help you with this but I am not fully sure what your final decision making is for 0, 1 customers. Where do they go by score? Can you add an accurate desired output for this dataset? You will have an answer pretty quickly after thta I suspect.

Comment: In response to a comment by run-out, which is appreciated by the way, so after all the customer types 2 to 5 have been picked, for each territory, then we pick those of type either 0 or 1 based on their score. Those with the highest score are picked first until we get to the 15th position, at which point the loop, if used, should exit, and iterate for another territory to fill another 15 positions. Customer types 2 to 5 get first priority, followed by types 0 and 1. Assume types 2 to 5 can be treated the same, while 0 and 1 are the same too.

Comment: if implemented correctly the final output for territory **JW** should be: `{'id': {43: 44,
  24: 25,
  78: 79,
  39: 40,
  77: 78,
  81: 82,
  58: 59,
  40: 41,
  57: 58,
  62: 63,
  48: 49,
  17: 18,
  72: 73},
 'score': {43: 16.203058,
  24: 0.38833429999999997,
  78: -0.030865802999999997,
  39: -0.09235809,
  77: -0.10221161,
  81: -0.10258331,
  58: -0.114151105,
  40: -0.115899056,
  57: -0.11875506,
  62: -0.120798856,
  48: -0.12162866,
  17: -0.1216441,
  72: -0.12164523}}`

Comment: I'm going to add this into your question.

Comment: Customers 0 and 1 are already in territories, should they be moved arbitrarily to other territories? Or should they be maintained intheir territroies and topped up from others?

Comment: I think the example isn't working because 15 in each territory is too large for the sample set. territory
JW    13
KO     7
MD     7
MP    14
PC     9
Name: id, dtype: int64

Comment: I can double the data set and add more cases, if that can make solution testing easier. However the goal is to have say 15 customers per territory, with those  of type [0,1] being picked based on the order of their score (high to low) after those of type [2,3,4,5] have been assigned first.

Comment: Thanks for your updates, do type[2,3,4,5] keep the territories they are in, or are they just assigned first to any territory?

Comment: Every customer stays in their territory. However the problem is that within a territory we pick only 15 customers. So assuming I had more data points than i gave you... customers of type 2,3,4,5 usually are going to be 60% of the pool of customers i'm looking for. The other 40% has to be filled by selecting customers of type 0,1 based on sorted scores. I imagined a solution to this problem as a while loop for each territory, which increments until it gets to 15, then exits and repeats for another territory until all territories have their 15 customers each.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had to step away for a while. Answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved quite easily using Pandas Library. First import pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
```

Then I'll use your data provided in the question above to create a dataframe.

```
data = {
    "id": {
        30: 31,
        71: 72,
        48: 49,
        3: 4,
        96: 97,
        27: 28,
        58: 59,
        47: 48,
        50: 51,
        81: 82,
        24: 25,
        57: 58,
        63: 64,
        12: 13,
        21: 22,
        29: 30,
        38: 39,
        53: 54,
        1: 2,
        97: 98,
        4: 5,
        75: 76,
        8: 9,
        43: 44,
        72: 73,
        41: 42,
        7: 8,
        0: 1,
        80: 81,
        64: 65,
        17: 18,
        67: 68,
        77: 78,
        13: 14,
        78: 79,
        95: 96,
        98: 99,
        18: 19,
        83: 84,
        39: 40,
        49: 50,
        62: 63,
        59: 60,
        19: 20,
        28: 29,
        32: 33,
        94: 95,
        76: 77,
        40: 41,
        25: 26,
    },
    "customer_type": {
        30: 0,
        71: 0,
        48: 0,
        3: 0,
        96: 0,
        27: 0,
        58: 0,
        47: 0,
        50: 0,
        81: 0,
        24: 0,
        57: 0,
        63: 0,
        12: 0,
        21: 0,
        29: 0,
        38: 0,
        53: 0,
        1: 0,
        97: 0,
        4: 1,
        75: 0,
        8: 2,
        43: 5,
        72: 0,
        41: 0,
        7: 0,
        0: 0,
        80: 0,
        64: 0,
        17: 0,
        67: 0,
        77: 1,
        13: 0,
        78: 0,
        95: 0,
        98: 0,
        18: 0,
        83: 2,
        39: 0,
        49: 0,
        62: 0,
        59: 0,
        19: 1,
        28: 0,
        32: 0,
        94: 0,
        76: 0,
        40: 0,
        25: 0,
    },
    "territory": {
        30: "MP",
        71: "MD",
        48: "JW",
        3: "KO",
        96: "PC",
        27: "MP",
        58: "JW",
        47: "KO",
        50: "MD",
        81: "JW",
        24: "JW",
        57: "JW",
        63: "MP",
        12: "MP",
        21: "PC",
        29: "PC",
        38: "MD",
        53: "PC",
        1: "MD",
        97: "MP",
        4: "PC",
        75: "MP",
        8: "MD",
        43: "JW",
        72: "JW",
        41: "MP",
        7: "MP",
        0: "MP",
        80: "MP",
        64: "MP",
        17: "JW",
        67: "PC",
        77: "JW",
        13: "KO",
        78: "JW",
        95: "MP",
        98: "KO",
        18: "PC",
        83: "MP",
        39: "JW",
        49: "KO",
        62: "JW",
        59: "PC",
        19: "MP",
        28: "PC",
        32: "MD",
        94: "MD",
        76: "KO",
        40: "JW",
        25: "KO",
    },
    "line_of_business": {
        30: "MS",
        71: "PL",
        48: "PL",
        3: "BK",
        96: "BK",
        27: "MS",
        58: "MS",
        47: "PL",
        50: "PL",
        81: "PL",
        24: "MS",
        57: "MS",
        63: "MS",
        12: "MS",
        21: "MS",
        29: "MS",
        38: "PL",
        53: "MS",
        1: "PL",
        97: "BK",
        4: "BK",
        75: "BK",
        8: "PL",
        43: "BK",
        72: "WH",
        41: "MS",
        7: "BK",
        0: "BK",
        80: "MS",
        64: "MS",
        17: "WH",
        67: "MS",
        77: "PL",
        13: "PL",
        78: "MS",
        95: "BK",
        98: "PL",
        18: "BK",
        83: "BK",
        39: "BK",
        49: "BK",
        62: "WH",
        59: "BK",
        19: "BK",
        28: "MS",
        32: "PL",
        94: "PL",
        76: "PL",
        40: "BK",
        25: "BK",
    },
    "score": {
        30: -0.11663294,
        71: -0.11386547,
        48: -0.12162866,
        3: -0.12182722,
        96: -0.11615907,
        27: -0.11718783,
        58: -0.114151105,
        47: 0.25628838,
        50: -0.12141464,
        81: -0.10258331,
        24: 0.38833429999999997,
        57: -0.11875506,
        63: -0.11688472,
        12: -0.12182722,
        21: -0.12166456,
        29: -0.12143712,
        38: -0.121612154,
        53: -0.1117985,
        1: 0.009443938,
        97: -0.08405101,
        4: -0.11209511,
        75: -0.11695675,
        8: -0.09269947,
        43: 16.203058,
        72: -0.12164523,
        41: -0.11750265,
        7: 0.23497310000000002,
        0: -0.12079343,
        80: -0.12140889,
        64: -0.09675851,
        17: -0.1216441,
        67: -0.11624039,
        77: -0.10221161,
        13: -0.120783366,
        78: -0.030865802999999997,
        95: -0.12078334,
        98: -0.12087545,
        18: -0.12182722,
        83: 2.497704,
        39: -0.09235809,
        49: -0.12162312,
        62: -0.120798856,
        59: -0.12138289,
        19: 0.45566094,
        28: -0.11319951,
        32: -0.028370887,
        94: -0.11610924,
        76: 0.006734696,
        40: -0.115899056,
        25: 0.208569,
    },
    "rank": {
        30: 100362,
        71: 87381,
        48: 198190,
        3: 219184,
        96: 95523,
        27: 112584,
        58: 89707,
        47: 21080,
        50: 180328,
        81: 67077,
        24: 12142,
        57: 145717,
        63: 104471,
        12: 222278,
        21: 205690,
        29: 184550,
        38: 193153,
        53: 74821,
        1: 29773,
        97: 41429,
        4: 76400,
        75: 107456,
        8: 53003,
        43: 256,
        72: 202272,
        41: 117718,
        7: 23262,
        0: 164623,
        80: 177756,
        64: 60792,
        17: 202027,
        67: 96223,
        77: 66835,
        13: 162515,
        78: 35534,
        95: 162508,
        98: 168744,
        18: 217151,
        83: 3956,
        39: 52385,
        49: 196564,
        62: 164880,
        59: 172787,
        19: 9120,
        28: 83165,
        32: 34985,
        94: 95174,
        76: 30020,
        40: 92385,
        25: 26342,
    },
}
```

Make a dataframe from 'data'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

   id  customer_type territory line_of_business      score    rank
0    1              0        MP               BK  -0.120793  164623
1    2              0        MD               PL   0.009444   29773
3    4              0        KO               BK  -0.121827  219184
4    5              1        PC               BK  -0.112095   76400
7    8              0        MP               BK   0.234973   23262
8    9              2        MD               PL  -0.092699   53003
12  13              0        MP               MS  -0.121827  222278
13  14              0        KO               PL  -0.120783  162515
17  18              0        JW               WH  -0.121644  202027
18  19              0        PC               BK  -0.121827  217151
19  20              1        MP               BK   0.455661    9120
21  22              0        PC               MS  -0.121665  205690
24  25              0        JW               MS   0.388334   12142
25  26              0        KO               BK   0.208569   26342
27  28              0        MP               MS  -0.117188  112584
28  29              0        PC               MS  -0.113200   83165
29  30              0        PC               MS  -0.121437  184550
30  31              0        MP               MS  -0.116633  100362
32  33              0        MD               PL  -0.028371   34985
38  39              0        MD               PL  -0.121612  193153
39  40              0        JW               BK  -0.092358   52385
40  41              0        JW               BK  -0.115899   92385
41  42              0        MP               MS  -0.117503  117718
43  44              5        JW               BK  16.203058     256
47  48              0        KO               PL   0.256288   21080
48  49              0        JW               PL  -0.121629  198190
49  50              0        KO               BK  -0.121623  196564
50  51              0        MD               PL  -0.121415  180328
53  54              0        PC               MS  -0.111798   74821
57  58              0        JW               MS  -0.118755  145717
58  59              0        JW               MS  -0.114151   89707
59  60              0        PC               BK  -0.121383  172787
62  63              0        JW               WH  -0.120799  164880
63  64              0        MP               MS  -0.116885  104471
64  65              0        MP               MS  -0.096759   60792
67  68              0        PC               MS  -0.116240   96223
71  72              0        MD               PL  -0.113865   87381
72  73              0        JW               WH  -0.121645  202272
75  76              0        MP               BK  -0.116957  107456
76  77              0        KO               PL   0.006735   30020
77  78              1        JW               PL  -0.102212   66835
78  79              0        JW               MS  -0.030866   35534
80  81              0        MP               MS  -0.121409  177756
81  82              0        JW               PL  -0.102583   67077
83  84              2        MP               BK   2.497704    3956
94  95              0        MD               PL  -0.116109   95174
95  96              0        MP               BK  -0.120783  162508
96  97              0        PC               BK  -0.116159   95523
97  98              0        MP               BK  -0.084051   41429
98  99              0        KO               PL  -0.120875  168744
```

Next we will sort the dataframe as follows:

1. territory: ascending
2. customer_type: descending
3. score: descending

Here's the code:

```
df = df.sort_values(['territory', 'customer_type', "score"], ascending=[True, False, False])

print(df)

   id  customer_type territory line_of_business      score    rank
43  44              5        JW               BK  16.203058     256
77  78              1        JW               PL  -0.102212   66835
24  25              0        JW               MS   0.388334   12142
78  79              0        JW               MS  -0.030866   35534
39  40              0        JW               BK  -0.092358   52385
81  82              0        JW               PL  -0.102583   67077
58  59              0        JW               MS  -0.114151   89707
40  41              0        JW               BK  -0.115899   92385
57  58              0        JW               MS  -0.118755  145717
62  63              0        JW               WH  -0.120799  164880
48  49              0        JW               PL  -0.121629  198190
17  18              0        JW               WH  -0.121644  202027
72  73              0        JW               WH  -0.121645  202272
47  48              0        KO               PL   0.256288   21080
25  26              0        KO               BK   0.208569   26342
76  77              0        KO               PL   0.006735   30020
13  14              0        KO               PL  -0.120783  162515
98  99              0        KO               PL  -0.120875  168744
49  50              0        KO               BK  -0.121623  196564
3    4              0        KO               BK  -0.121827  219184
8    9              2        MD               PL  -0.092699   53003
1    2              0        MD               PL   0.009444   29773
32  33              0        MD               PL  -0.028371   34985
71  72              0        MD               PL  -0.113865   87381
94  95              0        MD               PL  -0.116109   95174
50  51              0        MD               PL  -0.121415  180328
38  39              0        MD               PL  -0.121612  193153
83  84              2        MP               BK   2.497704    3956
19  20              1        MP               BK   0.455661    9120
7    8              0        MP               BK   0.234973   23262
97  98              0        MP               BK  -0.084051   41429
64  65              0        MP               MS  -0.096759   60792
30  31              0        MP               MS  -0.116633  100362
63  64              0        MP               MS  -0.116885  104471
75  76              0        MP               BK  -0.116957  107456
27  28              0        MP               MS  -0.117188  112584
41  42              0        MP               MS  -0.117503  117718
95  96              0        MP               BK  -0.120783  162508
0    1              0        MP               BK  -0.120793  164623
80  81              0        MP               MS  -0.121409  177756
12  13              0        MP               MS  -0.121827  222278
4    5              1        PC               BK  -0.112095   76400
53  54              0        PC               MS  -0.111798   74821
28  29              0        PC               MS  -0.113200   83165
96  97              0        PC               BK  -0.116159   95523
67  68              0        PC               MS  -0.116240   96223
59  60              0        PC               BK  -0.121383  172787
29  30              0        PC               MS  -0.121437  184550
21  22              0        PC               MS  -0.121665  205690
18  19              0        PC               BK  -0.121827  217151
```

Now we have a dataframe sorted by territory, with most important clients 2-5 at the top of each territory, and all in descending score order. Now we just have to restrict each territory to n customers. (I'm going to use 8 instead of 15 because of the small dataset.)

```
n = 8    
df = df.groupby('territory').head(n)

print(df)

   id  customer_type territory line_of_business      score    rank
43  44              5        JW               BK  16.203058     256
77  78              1        JW               PL  -0.102212   66835
24  25              0        JW               MS   0.388334   12142
78  79              0        JW               MS  -0.030866   35534
39  40              0        JW               BK  -0.092358   52385
81  82              0        JW               PL  -0.102583   67077
58  59              0        JW               MS  -0.114151   89707
40  41              0        JW               BK  -0.115899   92385
47  48              0        KO               PL   0.256288   21080
25  26              0        KO               BK   0.208569   26342
76  77              0        KO               PL   0.006735   30020
13  14              0        KO               PL  -0.120783  162515
98  99              0        KO               PL  -0.120875  168744
49  50              0        KO               BK  -0.121623  196564
3    4              0        KO               BK  -0.121827  219184
8    9              2        MD               PL  -0.092699   53003
1    2              0        MD               PL   0.009444   29773
32  33              0        MD               PL  -0.028371   34985
71  72              0        MD               PL  -0.113865   87381
94  95              0        MD               PL  -0.116109   95174
50  51              0        MD               PL  -0.121415  180328
38  39              0        MD               PL  -0.121612  193153
83  84              2        MP               BK   2.497704    3956
19  20              1        MP               BK   0.455661    9120
7    8              0        MP               BK   0.234973   23262
97  98              0        MP               BK  -0.084051   41429
64  65              0        MP               MS  -0.096759   60792
30  31              0        MP               MS  -0.116633  100362
63  64              0        MP               MS  -0.116885  104471
75  76              0        MP               BK  -0.116957  107456
4    5              1        PC               BK  -0.112095   76400
53  54              0        PC               MS  -0.111798   74821
28  29              0        PC               MS  -0.113200   83165
96  97              0        PC               BK  -0.116159   95523
67  68              0        PC               MS  -0.116240   96223
59  60              0        PC               BK  -0.121383  172787
29  30              0        PC               MS  -0.121437  184550
21  22              0        PC               MS  -0.121665  205690
```

Finally, in your question, you state you want the final output to be a dataframe with just the territory and client id.

```
print(df[['territory', 'id']])

  territory  id
43        JW  44
77        JW  78
24        JW  25
78        JW  79
39        JW  40
81        JW  82
58        JW  59
40        JW  41
57        JW  58
62        JW  63
48        JW  49
17        JW  18
72        JW  73
47        KO  48
25        KO  26
76        KO  77
13        KO  14
98        KO  99
49        KO  50
3         KO   4
8         MD   9
1         MD   2
32        MD  33
71        MD  72
94        MD  95
50        MD  51
38        MD  39
83        MP  84
19        MP  20
7         MP   8
97        MP  98
64        MP  65
30        MP  31
63        MP  64
75        MP  76
27        MP  28
41        MP  42
95        MP  96
0         MP   1
80        MP  81
12        MP  13
4         PC   5
53        PC  54
28        PC  29
96        PC  97
67        PC  68
59        PC  60
29        PC  30
21        PC  22
18        PC  19
```

** EDIT 
Edit made to combine customer types 0 and 1 so they don't get sorted. 
The way to do this is make a new column, in this case called 'customer_
type_sorter' and set all values for 0 and 1 the same, in this case -1. This way they will get treated the same.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['customer_type_sorter'] = df["customer_type"]
df.loc[df['customer_type'] < 2, 'customer_type_sorter'] = -1
df = df.sort_values(['territory', 'customer_type_sorter', "score"], ascending=[True, False, False])
n = 8
df_result = df.groupby('territory')['id', 'customer_type', 'score', 'territory'].head(n)
print(df_result)

    id  customer_type      score territory
43  44              5  16.203058        JW
24  25              0   0.388334        JW
78  79              0  -0.030866        JW
39  40              0  -0.092358        JW
77  78              1  -0.102212        JW
81  82              0  -0.102583        JW
58  59              0  -0.114151        JW
40  41              0  -0.115899        JW
47  48              0   0.256288        KO
25  26              0   0.208569        KO
76  77              0   0.006735        KO
13  14              0  -0.120783        KO
98  99              0  -0.120875        KO
49  50              0  -0.121623        KO
3    4              0  -0.121827        KO
8    9              2  -0.092699        MD
1    2              0   0.009444        MD
32  33              0  -0.028371        MD
71  72              0  -0.113865        MD
94  95              0  -0.116109        MD
50  51              0  -0.121415        MD
38  39              0  -0.121612        MD
83  84              2   2.497704        MP
19  20              1   0.455661        MP
7    8              0   0.234973        MP
97  98              0  -0.084051        MP
64  65              0  -0.096759        MP
30  31              0  -0.116633        MP
63  64              0  -0.116885        MP
75  76              0  -0.116957        MP
53  54              0  -0.111798        PC
4    5              1  -0.112095        PC
28  29              0  -0.113200        PC
96  97              0  -0.116159        PC
67  68              0  -0.116240        PC
59  60              0  -0.121383        PC
29  30              0  -0.121437        PC
21  22              0  -0.121665        PC
```

Comment: Hey **run-out**, I appreciate the work you have put into this. I think your solution is really close, but there is problem. For territory **PC** where all customers in this data set are types [0,1] they should be picked in order of their score. So customer id 54 should be picked before customer id 5, but in your case those two are reversed.

Comment: To clarify, customers of type 2 to 5 get picked automatically regardless of their score. Ordering by score only applies to types 0, 1 until the limit per territory is reached. Solution for territory **JW** is `jw_territory = pd.DataFrame({'id': {43: 44, 24: 25, 78: 79, 39: 40, 77: 78, 81: 82, 58: 59, 40: 41},
 'score': {43: 16.203058,
  24: 0.38833429999999997,
  78: -0.030865802999999997,
  39: -0.09235809,
  77: -0.10221161,
  81: -0.10258331,
  58: -0.114151105,
  40: -0.115899056},
 'customer_type': {43: 5, 24: 0, 78: 0, 39: 0, 77: 1, 81: 0, 58: 0, 40: 0}})`

Comment: That last edit should work. If you don't want to sort 2 - 5, then make them equal to a similar number in 'customer_type_sorter' as well.  Please select as correct if this works for you. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, your latest fix checks out. Greatly appreciated.